# call segue after genie effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am new to objective C, and I am trying to get into speed by doing some tutorial adding my own bit to it. I am working now with Genie effect from [Ciechan / BCGenieEffect](https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect). I think I understand the implementation since it seems to work for me, however I have a question, How could I trigger a segue after the end of the animation.

The code i am using is as follow:

```
- (void) genieToRect: (CGRect)rect edge: (BCRectEdge) edge
{

NSTimeInterval duration = 0.97;


CGRect endRect = CGRectInset(rect, 5.0, 5.0);

[self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    button.enabled = NO;
}];

if (self.viewIsIn) {
    [self.draggedView genieOutTransitionWithDuration:duration startRect:endRect startEdge:edge completion:^{
        self.draggedView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            button.enabled = YES;
        }];
    }];
} else {
    self.draggedView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.draggedView genieInTransitionWithDuration:duration destinationRect:endRect destinationEdge:edge completion:
     ^{
         [self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
             button.enabled = YES;
         }];}];
}

self.viewIsIn = ! self.viewIsIn;
}
```

I put a button to call the animation:

```
- (IBAction)leftButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{

[self genieToRect:sender.frame edge:BCRectEdgeTop]; 

}
```

Everything is working fine there, but now, I would like, when the animation ends, to call a segue to move to the next view (like Apple is doing in mail after you click for instance Trash - Once the mail arrive to the trash, the view change)

I tried to call a method inside the button method like this:

```
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prepareForSegue:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then I added my method like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"public" sender:self];
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work...

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If you do `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"public" sender:nil];` at the end of `lefButtonTapped:`?
And remove `prepareForSegue:sender:` method at all.
The order is calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, which automatically call `prepareForSegue::` in case it has to do something before segue.

Comment: @Larme: Hi, Larme. When I add `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"public" sender:nil];` at the end of    `lefButtonTapped:`unfortunately, it doesn't work. It changes the view before the animation starts. I really want it to change the view after the animation ends.

Comment: Call the segue in the block (after `...completion:^{[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"public" sender:nil];...`

Comment: @Larme Thank you, it works!. Now I just need to learn a bit more about the block. However, I have two different buttons, would you advice to put a if section within the block such as: `.... completion: ^{if(leftButton){[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"public" sender:nil];} else { [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"private" sender:nil];} ...

Comment: You can do it. I posted the answer for other viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` will call `prepareForSegue:identifier`. If you have something to do there (like passing information to the next ViewController at the end of the segue), you put your code in `prepareForSegue:identifier`.
So, remove `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` in `prepareForSegue:identifier`.

To perform the segue after the animation, put it in the block. Here, you have `...completion:^{}`. You put there what you want to do a the completion. So call here `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`.